# Better design approach for having a variable in a class not present in Database

Tags: java

Say I have a class:

```
class X {
  private int a;
  private int b;
  private int c;
}

id & d are a List as well.
List<X> result = getResult(id, d);
```

Now while processing result, I would like to have d as well. One way I can think of is by adding the variable d in the class X, and make getResult just keep appending d.

```
getResult(id, d) {
        foreach id {
            X x = databaseCall(id);
            x.d = d;
            result.add(x);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The drawback with this approach is that class X now no longer has values based on the columns in the DB. Is there a better way?

Comment: couldn't fully understand your drawback

Comment: It is calculated value, shouldn't be in DB

Comment: @user7790438 I am not storing in DB. I just wanted to know if it is good practice to add the extra variable in the class. Or should I create another class which has class X and my extra variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add @Transient annotation on a field that should not been persisted.